# how variables accessible in anonymous class?

Tags: java, servlets, anonymous-class, anonymous-inner-class

I have following code :

```
    class A  extends HttpServlet{
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletRespons
 response) throws ServletException, IOExceptio
           {
             String str= "String In doGet()";
               JsonBatchCallback<Users> callback = new
     JsonBatchCallback<Users>(){
              String inThisClass = str; // Showing me error 
        }
     }
     }
```

`str` is not accessible. How i can access `"str"`.

My Actual Code is as follows :

```
public class SyncTask extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    final  Logger logger    =   Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String domain        = request.getParameter("DomainName");
        String reqAdminEmail = request.getParameter("AdminEmail");
        String searchRegex   = request.getParameter("searchRegex");

        Boolean manualSync  =   false;

        if(reqAdminEmail != null){
            manualSync  =   true;
        }

        String adminEmail = "";

        try{

            Date startTime = new Date();

            Manager mangerObj = new Manager("MASTER");

            final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL              = Constant.getServiceAccountEmail();

            final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH   = Constant.getServiceAccountPkcs12FilePath();


            Collection<String> SCOPES = new ArrayList<String>();
            SCOPES.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user");
            SCOPES.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit");


            String nextToken = null;
            int noOfUsers    = 0;

            mangerObj = new Manager(domain);

            Configuration config = mangerObj.getConfiguration();
            if(config==null)
                return;
            else
                adminEmail = config.getAdminEmail();


            HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JacksonFactory jsonFactory  = new JacksonFactory();

            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
            .setServiceAccountUser(adminEmail)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                    new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
                    .build();

            Directory directoryService = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("Directory ").build();
            BatchRequest batch = directoryService.batch();

            do{

                List list = directoryService.users().list();
                list.setCustomer("my_customer");
                list.setMaxResults(500);
                list.setPageToken(nextToken);
                list.setFields("nextPageToken,users(relations,orgUnitPath,primaryEmail,name)");
                if(searchRegex != null ){
                    if(searchRegex.isEmpty() == false){
                        list.setQuery("email:"+searchRegex+"*");
                    }
                }

                JsonBatchCallback<Users> callback = new JsonBatchCallback<Users>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Users users, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {
                        nextToken = users.getNextPageToken(); // i'm not able to access  nextToken
                    }

                    public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError e, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {
                        System.out.println("Error Message: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                };

                list.queue(batch, callback);

            }while(nextToken != null);

            try {
                batch.execute();
            } catch(Exception ex){
                ErrorHandler.errorHandler(this.getClass().getName(), ex);
            }

        }catch(Exception ex){
            ErrorHandler.errorHandler(this.getClass().getName(), ex);
        }

    }
```

I have updated my code where actually i am getting error. I want to access `nextToken` into anonymous class,but i not able to accesss.

Error as follows :

```
nextToken cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Comment: why down vote this ?

Comment: because someone is so lame, so he gladly downvotes - but he's not man enough to explain why... ;)

Comment: _str is not accessible_ I don't believe you. Give us proof.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I didn't say it's accessible - only that this code can compile without an error (at least in Java 8 it is).

Comment: ok i update with my full code.

Comment: No, don't add your code if it's irrelevant. Add the error. And look it up before you do.

Comment: Did you get NullPointer exception ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis please take look into a code.

Comment: @Md.NasirUddinBhuiyan no compile time error.

Comment: Please add User class code

Comment: @Md.NasirUddinBhuiyan its in-build in API. What u want exactly to know?

Comment: make it final  `final String str= "String In doGet()";`. No you cannot modify a variable from within a inner class from its parent.  You can access it only if the variable is declared Final.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the `str` variable `final`.

As a matter of fact the `inThisClass` variable is redundant, at least in what you posted so far.

But your *actual* code shows a different error message from your sample code. Your actual code cannot be written, because you don't have write-access to local variables in enclosing scopes from anonymous classes. You will have to think of something else, such as a `final StringBuilder.`

Answer (score 0):

Declare `str` in doGet as `final`:

```
final String str = "String In doGet()";
```

Anonymous classes can access only final local variables of an outer method. In Java 8 it was changed.
Also your IDE should assist you with fixes of such errors.

Comment: 'Changed in Java 8' how? ['Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must either be declared final or be effectively final (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs where the use is attempted.'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) Is it the 'effectively final' part?